# use YQL with substring-before in xpath

Tags: xpath, substring, yql

I am trying to get a string before '--' within a paragraph in an html page using the xpath and send it to yql

for example i want to get the date from the following article:

```
<div>
<p>Date --- the body of the article</p>
</div>
```

I tried this query in yql:

```
select * from html where url="article url" and xpath="//div/p/text()/[substring-before(.,'--')]"
```

but it does not work.

how can I get the date of the article which is before the '--'

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
  substring-before(//div/p,'--')
```

Comment: @Ruba, I'm really sorry, I did a big mistake (I'm like stoned today). Now I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
substring-before(/div/p/text(), '--')
```

This XPath expression evaluates to the string immediately preceding `'--'` in the first text node in the XML document, that is a child of a `p` that is a child of the `div` top element.

**In case you want to get this value for every such text node**, you have to use an expression like:

```
substring-before((//div/p/text())[$k], '--')
```

and evaluate this expression `$N` times, for `$k = 1,2, ..., $N`

where `$N` is `count(//div/p/text())`

**Do note**: Try to avoid using the `//` XPath pseudo-operator always when the structure of the XML document is statically known. Using `//` usually results in big inefficiency (O(N^2)) that are felt especially painful on big XML documents.